# Wavelink - on_wavelink_track_end doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py

It appears that after playing a song, the subsequent songs in the queue are not automatically playing.

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_wavelink_track_end(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.YouTubeTrack, reason):
        guild = player.guild
        vc: player = guild.voice_client
        if vc.loop:
            return await player.play(track)
        if not player.queue.is_empty:
            next_song = await player.queue.get_wait()
            await player.play(next_song)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"正在播放  {next_song.title}")
```

and

```
    @app_commands.command(name="play", description="播放")
    @app_commands.describe(search="搜尋")
    async def play(self, interaction : discord.Interaction, search: str):
        guild = interaction.guild
        track = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(search, return_first=True)

        if not guild.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await interaction.user.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = guild.voice_client

        if vc.queue.is_empty and not vc.is_playing():
            await vc.play(track)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"正在播放  {track.title}")
        else:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(track)
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'新增  {track.title} 至佇列')

        setattr(vc, "loop", False)
```

How can I fix it ?

What parts need to be modified in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use wavelink 2.0+ you do not have to make autoplay yourself

Just add them to the `auto_queue` and set the `autoplay` attribute of the `wavelink.Player` instance to `True`

https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wavelink.html#wavelink.Player.auto_queue